# How do I render my partialview inside my main view or can I update the values in another way?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, partial-views, nopcommerce

I have the following problem: So I built a search function for an OrderId in Nopcommerce and I want to update two values (Buyer Name) and (Purchase Reason) in a table in my main view instead of how it is now, where I render them in a partial view but it appears on the main page.

Example:

[image: My search field, after I click search I want the result to appear below it without loading a new page]

How it is at the moment after I click search button :

[image: It pops up a new window with the results. Basically I want this panel here to appear in my first view as I explained earlier]

My controller that renders the partial view:

[image: I think I need to change something here right?]

And here:Part of my SearchResult.cshtml partial view where the values appear

[image: Part of my SearchResult.cshtml partial view where the values appear]

I want it to appear somewhere here (My startview.cshtml as you can see I tried some things but nothing seems to work, Ill delete those)
[image: I want it to appear somewhere here (My startview.cshtml as you can see I tried some things but nothing seems to work, Ill delete those)]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: some parts of the code contain sensitive information to the company and if I just leave it out it makes no sense either, I want to show the context. If you click on the screenshots you can see the code clearly

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."*

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557): *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way, such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using ajax call.

```
            var request = {
                OrderId: $('#OrderId').val(),
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/DisplayBuyerName",
                type: "GET",
                data: request,
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#SearchResult").html('').html(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

html:

```
<div id="SearchResult"> </div>
```

So now your partial view is placed in `SearchResult` div.